# Oauth social login services not working

Tags: services, authentication-authorization

Can any body help me out how do I accomplish social networking login using login using [loginprovider](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauthloginprovider).

I have done this for website using oauth connector.

I tried lot but no success for mobile services. What should I pass in parameters, end point I got is something like http://www.example.com/oauthlogin/api/login/info.json. Any body having  idea how legged process is done through [oauth 3.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauth) and [services 3.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/services). Or any other options available?

Answer (score 0):

I use [HybridAuth Social Login](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) for login system via social networks

Comment: This module doesn't working with services module.